# I would like to replace the link text in a menu with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to replace the link text in a menu with images. The menu is generated using rapidweaver so I cannot alter any of the template HTML itself, except the text contained inside the link. E.g.

```
<a href="http://truehealth.gr/eng/" rel="">!UK!</a>
```

My idea for a workaround is to put unique placeholder text in the menu links I want to replace with images. E.g. `!UK!`. Then, replace the placeholders with my images.

I think I can use JavaScript or jQuery for this but don't know how to do the find and replace.

Thanks

Comment: Simply put, if you can only include text (not html) in the link, then this is not possible. If you can use html, just use an image element with a base64 encoded image. (Though I imagine you're mistaken, and you can in-fact export the generated html from your design tool and do it properly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this very hacky solution will help you, assuming you can use some custom jQuery on the page.

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  // Check if the link text is a match
  if($(this).html() == "!UK!") {
    // Replace link text with image
    $(this).html("<img src='http://placehold.it/100x100'>");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://truehealth.gr/eng/" rel="">!UK!</a>
```

Comment: Wow that is perfect. Thank you so much

Comment: Can you mark the answer correct please.

Comment: How can i reverse the [on Hold]?